Why do we have to construct a Borel set $A$ when dealing with the proof of differentiating measures

This is a proof of the Theorem 3.22 in Real Analysis by Folland. I cannot understand the process of constructing a Borel set $A$. Why do we have to construct it and why is it suffices to prove the result for $x\in A$ instead of considering all possible points?

The content of $d\nu=d\lambda + f dm$ is that:

$\lambda$ and $m$ are singular, i.e. we can write $\mathbb{R}=A\cup B$ for some Borel sets $A$ and $B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $\lambda(A)=0=m(B)$. This is equivalent to what you've written because $B=A^c$.

for every Borel set $E$,
$$\nu(E)=\lambda(E)+\int_E fdm$$


The existence of the sets $A$ and $B$ follows from the Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem, which lets you write $\nu$ as $\lambda+\mu$ where $\lambda$ is singular with respect to $m$ and $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $m$. One then applies the Radon-Nikodym Theorem to $\mu$ to obtain $d\mu=fd m$ for some non-negative $f$.
Since $m(A^c)=0$ and we only want the identity to hold for $m$-almost every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, it suffices to consider those $x\in A$.
